# Is there a BigInt large number class in the standard library?

Tags: c++, std, biginteger, bigint, largenumber

Does the standard library have a `BigInt` class? (numbers with many digits held in a container)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The C++ standard library (sometimes erroneously referred to as "STL") does not contain any extended precision support.

Comment: Why is Standard Template Library erroneously called STL?

Comment: @Cristy, STL is the name of a specific template library implementation that predates the C++ standardization, which is mostly but not completely compatible. I might have been a little harsh, I remember now Scott Meyers' book is called "Effective STL" - if such an authority still uses the term, it should be OK for the rest of us.

Comment: The STL is just a small part of the C++ standard library.

Comment: The Standard Template Library *is* the STL, but STL does not refer to the C++ standard library. The Standard Template Library is just a small part of the C++ standard library as Chris Dodd said. The C++ standard library contains the STL and more. I hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: @Phoenix, the truth is more nuanced than that - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about

Comment: @MarkRansom in light of that comment perhaps you could remove the word "erroneously" from your answer...

Comment: @MattMcNabb I still think it's an error, just one that's easily forgiven. As humans we appreciate having simple names for things. Ask Xerox and Kleenex how they feel about that subject.

Answer (score 8):

No, but [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/)/[GMP](http://gmplib.org/) have C++ interfaces.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the C++ standard library does not natively support arbitrarily long integers. However, these libraries can help you getting the job done:

- [The GNU
  Multiple Precision
  Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/) (has both C and C++ interfaces, also refered as GMP)
- [InfInt](https://sercantutar.github.io/infint/)
- [C++ BigInt class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/)
- [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)
- [Multiple Precision Integers and Rationals](https://github.com/wbhart/mpir) (written in assembly, has a C interface)
- [BigDigits multiple-precision arithmetic](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/bigdigits.html) (in C)
- [BigIntegerCPP](https://github.com/technophilis/BigIntegerCPP) (only supports addition and multiplication)
- [C++ Big Integer Library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) (no longer maintained)