# how do I declare an integer variable of 1024 bits in length?

Tags: c++, variable-types, unsigned-long-long-int

I'm trying to write an algorithm for a number theory/computer science merged class that can factor large numbers in better than exponential time. I am using the g++ compiler on a 64 bit machine but when I chain together `long` it will only allow me to do up to 2 longs. Is there any way to tell it to use an arbitrary amount of space for a variable?

Comment: I would check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344049/c-how-do-i-store-a-256-bit-number-and-how-do-i-convert-it-to-hex.  The idea is the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ handling very large integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124332/c-handling-very-large-integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a library.  A good one is http://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 3):

If you want just a collection of longs, you can declare an array of longs. But you don't want that. You want https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/ BigIntegers :-)

Alternatives:

http://gmplib.org/

http://www.mpir.org/

(disclaimer: I haven't tested/used them)

Or if you want to implement them

[How to implement big int in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269268/how-to-implement-big-int-in-c)

I'll add that the C++ std library doesn't contain a big integer implementation (source [STL big int class implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997363/stl-big-int-class-implementation) )