# Large number of float digits without extra library

Tags: c++, arbitrary-precision, precision, floating-point-precision

i have a float value that is hundreds of digits long (like the first 100 digits of pi - 3) and need a way to operate on it. is there any way to store and operate on the float that has a large number of decimals and maintain much precision with built in libraries? is there anything like python's Decimal module in c++?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: With the C++ Standard library - no.

Comment: @KevinDTimm - Unless you hand roll one yourself

Answer (score 5):

The other answers all point to high precision **integer** libraries. There are however a few **floating point libraries** around:

- [The High Precision Arithmetic library](http://www.nongnu.org/hpalib/)
- The [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/) (GMP) "Arithmetic without limitations"
- The GNU multiple-precision floating-point computations with correct rounding ([the GNU MPFR library](http://www.mpfr.org/)). There's also a [C++ wrapper](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/mpfr/).
- [NTL](http://shoup.net/ntl/): A Library for doing Number Theory. Together with [NTL::RR](http://shoup.net/ntl/doc/RR.txt) you can use this even within [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/using_udt/use_ntl.html).
- [The LBNL](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/) double-double precision, quad-double precision and arbitrary precision software.

... and don't forget the possibility that you can always implement your own solution. (Might not be the most effective or fastest solution, but it's "the" solution if you want to learn something.

Answer (score 2):

No built-in library, but you can do that using Bignum arithmetics :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic.

What a Bignum is: an array (vector) of digits. You can easily implement sum/difference....

I've actually asked something simillar here: [STL big int class implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997363/stl-big-int-class-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is some extra exotic platform, where a float is 100+ bytes long, you will find it hard to archive what you want without a library for big numbers.